# What's the given name for a String that's capitalized to the first character, lower-cased and trimmed?

Tags: string, language-agnostic

When creating a piece of code, I came to the situation in which I had to perform some operations over a String:

1. Turn it to lower-case
2. Turn the first character to Capital Case
3. Remove any trailing or leading whitespace

So that the following happens to the strings:

- "Foo Bar Baz " -> "Foo bar baz"
- "                 bar" -> "Bar"
- etc.

What is the name of this sort of String? I know we have `CAPITALIZEDSTRING`, `camelCasedString`, `PascalCasedString`and some others.

Comment: Does it need to have a name?

Comment: I'm trying to create a function that process the String through this pipeline, and couldn't think of a name for it. Something like `toSnakeCase` or `toCammelCase` would be easy and clear, So I wanted to see if there was a name for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, you would name it:

[Sentence case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Case_styles):

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

A mixed-case style in which the first word of the sentence is capitalised, as well as proper nouns and other words as required by a more specific rule.